# How many dyno hours have been used so far?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

Is there a way to see how many dyno hours you have used so far this month on Heroku? I know it's on the invoice you get, but I want some "live" data.

I use some "One off processes" (heroku run rake...) quite often and want to track this somehow.

Comment: I swear the other day that the 'My Account' page on Heroku showed you current spend for the current billing period but it's not there anymore.

Comment: https://api.heroku.com/invoices/current

Comment: Well, that seems to be the latest invoice only. It ranges from May 01 - June 01, 2012. What about June 01 - Today. That's what I want to see. I don't like to get the surprise at the end of the month :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was a bug.

Contacted Heroku support and they fixed it. You can see current usage here: https://api.heroku.com/account

Comment: Just as a quick comment. There is a bug in the system so the "Current usage" is not visible the first part of a new month. Maybe for a week or so I'd guess.